# wordpress with WP_QUERY and javascript "Onclick" doesn't works

Tags: wordpress, onclick, custom-post-type

Please Help Me

I can not make my custom post type to appear in div show and hide the content of each post. 
The same post when the second appears in this case. 
Please help me I am not able to resolve this problem.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'coleccoes', 'orderby' => 'date', 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tag-series', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'casegoods'))));  ?>  

             <div id="coleccao_casegood">

                    <?php if ( $loop ) :   

                         while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?> 

<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText-<?php the_ID() ?>");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
} 
</script>

<a href="javascript:toggle('toggleText-<?php the_ID(); ?>');"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<div id="toggleText-<?php the_ID() ?>" style="display: none"><h1><?php the_content(); ?></h1></div>

                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>  

                <?php endif; ?>  

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure you move the JS function outside of the loop, else it would just output for each found post.

Interestingly, you call the toggle function with the ID of the element as a parameter, but the function is not defined with parameters. Thus, the toggle function should look like this:

```
function toggle(elemID) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(elemID);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

With this in place it will work as expected. The function takes the element ID as parameter, gets the element with that ID and sets the styling. Anyway, I am pretty sure this is what you had in mind.

Also, do not forget to insert a wp_reset_postdata() at the end of the loop.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'coleccoes', 'orderby' => 'date', 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tag-series', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'casegoods'))));  ?>  

    <div id="coleccao_casegood">

        <?php if ( $loop ) :   

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?> 

                <a href="javascript:toggle('toggleText-<?php the_ID(); ?>');"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <div id="toggleText-<?php the_ID() ?>" style="display:none;"><h1><?php the_content(); ?></h1></div>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>  

    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>  

    </div>

<script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle(elemID) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(elemID);
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
    } 
</script>
```